# Composite component backing bean location

Tags: jsf-2, facelets, composite-component, backing-beans

I'm trying to split my JSF2 pages into composite components. So I decided to put the composite components in a logical file tree. For example:

> WebContent/resources/components/page1/component1.xhtml

The associated bean is in

> Java resources/src/components/page1/component1.java

Its package is this `components.page1`.

In this example, `component1.xhtml` is found and rendered, but the bean is not found by the server.

If I don't use a subpackage:

> WebContent/resources/page1/component1.xhtml
>   Java resources/src/page1/component1.java

So when the class is in the package `page1`, it works!

Is there a problem with composite component beans and subpackages?

I am using MyFaces 2.0, Tomcat 6 and Eclipse.

Comment: It should just work either way. Perhaps your definition of "backing bean" is not entirely right. Perhaps you mean "backing component". Is it a JSF `@ManagedBean`? Don't you actually mean the `UIComponent` implementation which is a `@FacesComponent`?

Comment: Yes it's rather a backing component that extends UIComponentBase. It is not a managed bean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the `componentType` attribute of [`<cc:interface>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/composite/interface.html) to explicitly specify the backing component.

```html
<cc:interface componentType="component1">
```

with

```
package components.page1;

@FacesComponent("component1")
public class Component1 extends UINamingContainer {
    // ...
}
```